# Django-Filters returns incorrect data

Tags: django, django-filters

I have two models `Products` and `Categories`. I am using `django-fliters` to filter my queryset but in some cases its returning incorrect data. When I filter the products with parameter `ParentCaregory = 1`, it filters the correct data.

[image: Correct]

But when I filter the products with parameter `ParentCaregory = 3` it returns incorrect data

[image: Incorrect]

As you can see its returning incorrect data.

These are my models:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
     parent_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     second_level_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     third_level_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     product = models.ForeignKey(to=Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Products(models.Model):
    product_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)  # creating primary key
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And this is the Filter Class I am using

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

from data_tool.models import Products


class DataFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    brand = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    shop_url = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    warranty = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    weight = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    categories__parent_category = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    categories__second_level_category = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    categories__third_level_category = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    marketplace_status = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    product_status = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    refund_and_return_policy = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    attribute_set = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    warrenty = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ['brand', 'shop_url', 'warranty', 'weight', 'categories__parent_category',
                  'categories__second_level_category', 'categories__third_level_category',
                  'marketplace_status', 'product_status', 'refund_and_return_policy', 'attribute_set', 'warrenty']
```

Comment: You are filtering _products_ not categories, categories have a foreign key to a product, meaning there can be multiple for the same product. So a filtered product can have a category which is different from your filter. As you can see the product id is 4 **two times** in your table (one correctly with 3 as you want the other with 4).

Comment: Yes I understand that. I thought the same when I saw the results. So how can I filter the products with respect to the categories??